# wxMaxima - solve / rearrange for term that contains certain variables

Tags: maxima, simplify, reformat

I would like to rearrange an equation in a way that certain variables only appear on the left side using wxMaxima.

```
%i: eq: term1 = term2 ;
%i: fun(eq,[v]);
%o: term3 = term4
```

Where the allowed symbols for the terms would be something like this:

- term1 = all
- term2 = all
- term3 = only [v] and operators
- term4 = all but [v]
- [v]   = the variable (or list) that I want to be on the left side

I tried to get something done with `matchdeclare` and `defrule` but I couldn't even get the `b` of `a=b+c` to the left side. I am not even sure if defrule is the correct approach as term 1 and 2 have nothing to do with 3 and 4. Is there a way to solve for lists?

**UPDATE:**

I came up with "something". It is not yet what I initially wanted, but at least closer. 
It is basically a substitution. I can provide a left hand side and the function tries to solve for it. Of course this exact left side might not be possible so that some variables remain on the right side. But one can specify one variable that should be eliminated on the right.

```
expr: a=b+c*d+e $
left: log(a+b) $
notright: b $
solve_form( expr, left, notright);
```

results in:

```
[log(b+a)=log(-e-c*d+2*a)]
```

Now, if I instead choose `log(a-b)` for the left side the output is:

```
[log(a-b)=log(e+c*d)]
```

which is pretty much what I wanted. Variables `a` and `b` are on the left side, but not on the right.
But I have to give an explicit left side. I would love to have a function that would find an arbitrary left side on its own so that neither `a` nor `b` are on the right side.

The obvious solution would have been:`[a-b=e+c*d]`

Function:

```
solve_form(expr,lterm,substvar) := block(
    [z],
    lterm: z = lterm,
    solve(lterm,substvar),
    ev(expr,%%),
    solve(%%,z),
    ev(%%,lterm)    
)$
```

Alternative function that does not need the `notright` input.

```
solveform(expr,zz_term) := block(
    [z,zz_term_vars,slist],
    zz_term: zz = zz_term,
    zz_term_vars: listofvars(rhs(zz_term)),
    slist:[],
    for i:1 thru length(zz_term_vars) do block(
        solve(zz_term,zz_term_vars[i]),
        ev(expr,%%),
        slist: append(slist,solve(%%,zz))
    ),
    listify(setify(ev(slist,zz_term)))
)$
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `solve`, `linsolve`, `algsys`, and `eliminate` have more or less the effect you are looking for.

Comment: I am not sure how exactly those would be helpful to solve my problem better. I updated the question to clarify it a bit more.